# C++ Constructor Code is working fine on Windows but not compiling on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, constructor

Here's the Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

enum class OrderBookType{bid, ask};

class OrderBookEntry{
    public:

        OrderBookEntry( double _price,
                        double _amount,
                        std::string _timeStamp,
                        std::string _product,
                        OrderBookType _orderType)
        {
            price = _price;
            amount= _amount;
            timeStamp= _timeStamp;
            product= _product;
            orderType= _orderType;
        }

        double price;
        double amount;
        std::string timeStamp;
        std::string product;
        OrderBookType orderType;

};

int main(){

    OrderBookEntry order1{102000.01, 0.0001, "2020/03/17 17:01:24.884492", "ETH/BTC", OrderBookType::bid};

    std::cout << "price: " << std::fixed << order1.price << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

***The error I'am getting:***

```
main.cpp:5:6: warning: scoped enumerations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
enum class OrderBookType{bid, ask};
     ^
main.cpp:33:20: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'OrderBookEntry'
    OrderBookEntry order1{102000.01, 0.0001, "2020/03/17 17:01:24.884492", "ETH/BTC", OrderBookType::bid};
                   ^
main.cpp:7:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
class OrderBookEntry{
      ^
main.cpp:10:9: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 5 arguments, but 0 were provided
        OrderBookEntry( double _price,
        ^
main.cpp:33:26: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    OrderBookEntry order1{102000.01, 0.0001, "2020/03/17 17:01:24.884492", "ETH/BTC", OrderBookType::bid};
                         ^
                         ;
1 warning and 2 errors generated.
```

Comment: please add compilation line (`clang ...` or `gcc ...`)

Comment: can't reproduce https://godbolt.org/z/oPe4G7oo7 your compiler by default uses old C++ standard. Add switch `-std=c++11` (or better).

Comment: You should be able to compile just by using the `-std=c++11` flag.

Comment: you need to set the target standard in xcode to C++11 or later.

Comment: Double-check the _version_ of the compiler you are using.  It must support c++11 _at least_.  When C++11 first came out, the default setting for compilers was to build in C++03 mode, until you set a compiler command line flag -std=c++11.  New compilers have raised the default language level so you won't need to do this.  I highly recommend using a newer compiler if you can, as the language (and their support for it) has improved considerably since then.

Answer (score 0):

As the compiler error indicates, enum class are supported only from C++ 11 onwards, so when you compile, you must pass a flag/switch or param to your c++ compiler to use that version of the language syntax, then only it will compile your OrderBookType::bid last argument passed in the constructor.